# Convolution product definition

Tags: functional-analysis

I have some questions concerning the definition and properties of the convolution:

We defined it as follows:

$f\ast g(x) := \int f(x-y)g(y) \mathrm{d} m^d (y)$ if integrable, and $0$ else where $m^d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure.
What are conditions on $f$ and $g$ in order to give this expression a sense (well-definedness).

Or better to say, for properties to be proven like $f\ast g = g\ast f$ or $(f\ast g) \ast h = f\ast (g \ast h)$, what do we need, that these things make sense?

Thank you all!

Comment: $f \ast g$ is defined (almost everywhere) for $f,g\in L^1$, or $f\in C_c$ and $g\in L^1_{loc}$. For example $L^1$ is a commutative banach algebra with convolution as product. There are obviously other cases in which $f \ast g$ is well defined.

Comment: ok, but isnt is possible to give general conditions such that the statements above make sense?

Comment: when ever the convolution is well defined ... I doubt that this is what you have in mind.

Comment: ok let us start with when is the convolution (as definded above) well-defined? I am looking for generall conditions...